# Notice: Undefined index: pre in C:\wamp\www\blog\news.php on line 164

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I am making a blog for myself in Dreamweaver and well I have run into some trouble, I want to display text from a database and yet it won't work for some reason. I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: pre in C:\wamp\www\blog\news.php on line 164
>   This is the block of code where the error is:

```
  <div id="blog_posts">
<?php do { ?>
  <h2><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></h2>
  <p class="updated"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['formatted']; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row_getDisplay['pre']; ?></p>
  <?php } while ($row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay)); ?>
```

Can anyone please help? I have been trying for days!

Comment: You should learn what "undefined index" means, that will probably shed some light into your issue.

Comment: Try echo isset($row_getDisplay['pre']) ? $row_getDisplay['pre'] : 'no value for pre';

Comment: is there `pre` index in your `$row_getDisplay` variable? is there some `pre` in your sql query?

Comment: just check the content of your array, do `echo "<pre>",print_r($row_getDisplay, TRUE),"</pre>"` so that you can its contents, probably there is no index `pre` inside

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while(...) { }` loop instead of `do { } while(...)` loop so `$row_getDisplay` is initialized on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In your array there are not index 'pre'...

You can use

```
echo isset($row_getDisplay['pre'])?$row_getDisplay['pre']:'';
```

for using your code with incorrect index.

Answer (score 0):

PHP indicating the problem is that there index "pre". Try to make an inspection of the variable $ row_getDisplay using var_dump() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). With this function you can check if the "pre" exists in the array of fields.

```
<div id="blog_posts">
<?php do { ?>
<?php var_dump($row_getDisplay); ?>
  <h2><?php echo $row_getDisplay['title']; ?></h2>
  <p class="updated"><?php echo $row_getDisplay['formatted']; ?></p>
  <p><?php echo $row_getDisplay['pre']; ?></p>
  <?php } while ($row_getDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($getDisplay)); ?>
```

Regards!.

Answer (score 0):

just check the content of your array, do echo `"<pre>",print_r($row_getDisplay, TRUE),"</pre>"` so that you can its contents, probably there is no `pre` index pre inside